# Delphi, что произойдет при A[i] := A[i+1] если A: array of TShape?

Tags: delphi

Это будет присваиванием ссылок? Т.е. после выполнения этой операции A[i] и A[i+1] будут ссылаться на один и тото же Shape?

Comment: Запустите в дебаггере и посмотрите,  будет полезно.

Answer (score 3):

да

Comment: @hovadur, всю интригу запороли )